# Select files in a dir that have more than 'n' lines in shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, find, xargs

I am trying to select files that have more than 'n' number of lines in a shell script and move them to another directory.

The following command works fine from the command line but not in ashell script,

```
MY_PATH='/var/www/'
find $MY_PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'authuser-*' | xargs  wc -l |   awk '{if($1 >= 5) print $1}
```

But when in a shell script,

```
files_count=`find $MY_PATH -type f  -name 'authuser-*' | xargs  wc -l | awk '{if($1 > 5) print $2}'`
echo $files_count
exit 1
```

I am currently using this full command

```
find /var/www/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'authuser-*'| xargs  wc -l |   awk '{if($1 >= 5) print $2}' | awk '{if($1 !="total") print $1}' | xargs -i basename {} | head -$5
```

What could be the problem? is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the find command :

```
find "$MY_PATH" -type f  -name 'authuser-*'
```

you missed the double quotes.
BTW,the below script works at my place.

```
#!/bin/sh
mypah='./'
var=`find "$mypah" -name "temp" | xargs nawk '{a[FILENAME]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>5)print i}}'`

echo $var
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think you throwing in too many piped commands to do a simple job. Consider this for selecting all the files with lines greater than 5:

```
 find /var/www/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'authuser-*' \
                    -exec awk 'END {if (NR > 5) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Comment: Its just a back slash not a pipe to show you full command with scroll bars. Backslash is used in shells as line continuation character.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set *your* PATH in the script? 
`PATH='/var/www/'`

Otherwise, your script will use the system's PATH variable as opposed to the PATH you set. Apart from this, I don't see why your command 
won't work in the script if it does from the command line.

Also, you shouldn't use `PATH` for setting your custom path. You can choose 
a different name like `MY_PATH`, for example.

Comment: No actually, i haven't used PATH. That's my worry awk '{if($1 >= 5) print $2}' passes for all files

Comment: That means all files have at least 5 lines. Try with higher number like 100.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're making it MUCH more complicated than necessary:

```
n=5
for file in authuser-*
do
    (( $(wc -l <"$file") > "$n" )) &&
    mv "$file" wherever...
done
```

Note that the above will handle files with white space in their names just fine unlike any of the solutions that populate a variable with a list of files.